# Pm2 is hanging when stating as well as killing the processes

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using pm2 as my process manager for nodeJS . But sometimes it hangs and it's a pain for me.
[image]

I tried to uninstall pm2 as well but when I again installed it same error came.

Comment: Can you share the options you are using to start this process (specially the process file if you use one) ?

Comment: Post your PM2 configuration file of you want an answer

Comment: The option is pm2 start config.json --env test

Comment: The config file is same as provided on pm2 keymetrics site.

Answer (score 0):

you can tried look for from logs

```
~/.pm2/logs/test-out.log
```